# Errors when installing Ruby to Mac OSX Lion via RVM

Tags: installation, ruby, xcode, osx-lion

I was trying to install the newest version of Ruby via RVM, after I upgraded my Mac to Lion and installed the new Xcode 4.1 from the App store. I get this error in the log:

```
[2011-07-20 16:57:15]  ./configure
--prefix=/Users/justin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290 --enable-shared
--disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/justin/.rvm/usr

configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml-dir 
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.0.0 
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.0.0 
checking target system type...i386-apple-darwin11.0.0
checking for gcc... no 
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/justin/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290': 
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH 
See `config.log' for more details
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

This in the terminal:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #extracted to /Users/justin/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290 (already extracted)
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/justin/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/justin/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/justin/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/justin/.rvm/usr"  ', please read /Users/justin/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/justin/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
ERROR: Error running '/usr/bin/make ', please read /Users/justin/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/yaml/make.log
Installing yaml to /Users/justin/.rvm/usr
ERROR: Error running '/usr/bin/make install', please read /Users/justin/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/yaml/make.install.log
ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #configuring 
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/justin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/justin/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/justin/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/configure.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
Migrating gems from ruby-1.9.2-p180 to ruby-1.9.2-p290
ERROR: Ruby 'ruby-1.9.2-p290' is not installed - please install it first.
ERROR: Error migrating gems.
```

My $PATH is:

- `/opt/local/bin`
- `/opt/local/sbin`
- `/Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin`
- `/Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin`
- `/Users/justin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin`
- `/Users/justin/.rvm/bin`
- `/usr/bin`
- `/bin`
- `/usr/sbin`
- `/sbin`
- `/usr/local/bin`
- `/usr/X11/bin`
- `/usr/local/mysql/bin`

And neither `gcc` nor `cc` are found.

```
 ~ $ type gcc
-bash: type: gcc: not found
 ~ $ 
 ~ $ type cc
-bash: type: cc: not found
 ~ $
```

Comment: "no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH". That is quite clear. "See `config.log' for more details". What does it say in this file?

Comment: nothing ... so I guess it's not that clear, is it?

Comment: Well the basic problem is that you don't seem to have a compiler in your $PATH. Show us the output of `echo $PATH`. What happens when you enter `type gcc` or `type cc`? Just [edit] the info into your question.

Comment: You might want to reinstall Xcode, as it probably didn't really install everything properly (or failed to put everything into its right place).

Comment: Problem is it won't let me download it now, because the app store says it's already installed. I'm trying to download 4, but the developer site is having some trouble.

Comment: I'm also not sure if `i386` is wrong here. Not too familiar with C building on OS X though.

Comment: So, I found something interesting out by checking the install log in the console -- the app store doesn't actually download and install Xcode. It downloads Xcode Installer, which I guess I should've known -- though they don't say that. Every other piece of software I've downloaded from the app store has just installed. Not sure how it killed my previous Xcode install, but I'm running the 4.1 installer now.

Comment: I read on HN that XCode 4.1 no longer ships with GCC 4.0 (only 4.2+). Does RVM require GCC 4.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll post the answer here for anyone else having the same trouble. The App Store seems to have killed my Xcode 3.2.2 install without actually installing 4.1 (maybe it would work better with a new version of Xcode installed, or no version at all). The App Store did download an `Install Xcode.app` file, which I used to complete the install -- it did this silently, without any notice.

Once Xcode was up and running correctly again, Ruby complied just fine.

Comment: This saved my day (and confirmed my already strong suspicions that the App Store is getting in my way as a user rather than help me). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The new XCode, 4.3, appears to have a Downloads in its preferences that allows you to install the commandline tools.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the command line tools in Xcode (ver. 4.5.2) (see Preferences -> Downloads) fixed the "no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH" problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to OS X 10.7, but before updating to Xcode 4.1, I got the same "No acceptable C compiler" error message when trying to install ruby1.9.2-p290.

Trying to edit `PATH` did *not* help in solving this issue.

After the Xcode 4.1 update, though, everything is running fine, as usual:

```
cd ruby-1.9.x-pyyy
./configure --enable-shared --enable-pthread CFLAGS=-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=1
make
sudo make install
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.0.0]
```